What caused the worldwide blackout?
The fourth season of the Spanish series Estoy Vivo (I'm Alive) begins with a brief blackout that affects the entire world, and even the Pasarela (the Bridge or the Walkway), a sort of extraterrestrial afterlife waiting room, basically causing the death of everyone there, save the Director—to the extent that they were alive in the first place, of course.
When the Director talks to Adriana, she says that the blackout was not a coincidence, but does not seem to explain what caused it; the obvious candidate would be Elena Gamboa, but everyone, including her, talks as if she simply had taken advantage of the capsules having been lost in the fall of the Pasarela, even though she did kidnap the Returned, and it is difficult to imagine her being able to cause a planetwide blackout, to say nothing of one that basically affected Heaven.
Who or what caused the blackout at the beginning of the fourth season of Estoy Vivo?
